# Why am I obtaining this "These credentials do not match our records" message after a Custom User Providers authentication in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am pretty new in **PHP** and in **Laravel**.

I am following this tutorial to implement a **custom user provider**:

https://blog.georgebuckingham.com/laravel-52-auth-custom-user-providers-drivers/

I am using **Laravel 5.3** version.

I briefly explain what I need: my **Laravel** application is only a front end application, all the business logic, included the user authentication, is performed by a **Java back end application** that exposes **REST web services**.

Performing a call to:

```
http://localhost:8080/Extranet/login
```

and passing username and password as basic authentication I obtain a JSON response like this that represent the logged user:

```
{
  "userName": "Painkiller",
  "email": "painkiller@gmail.com",
  "enabled": true
}
```

So, in my Laravel application, I have to perform this call and then parse the previous returned **JSON object** to generate the authenticated object into the front end application session.

I have implemented all the 4 steps of the previous tutorial and I think that I have correctly replaced the user provider with my custom user provider that perform the web service call, this is my code:

It is not yet complete but it seems to works fine because submitting the Laravel login form of the **http://localhost:8000/login** page it enter into the **retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)** method and the call to my REST web service is correctly performed.

At this time I am not using the inserted credential but I am mocking it only because I am lazy and I don't want to insert username and password in the login form every time that I do a test...

Reading also this official tutorial:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers

it says that:

> The **retrieveByCredentials** method receives the array of credentials
>   passed to the **Auth::attempt** method when attempting to sign into an
>   application. **The method should then "query" the underlying persistent
>   storage for the user matching those credentials.** Typically, this
>   method will run a query with a "where" condition on
>   $credentials['username']. **The method should then return an
>   implementation of Authenticatable**. This method should not attempt to
>   do any password validation or authentication.
>
> The **validateCredentials** method **should compare the given $user with the
>   $credentials to authenticate the user**. For example, this method should
>   probably use Hash::check to compare the value of
>   $user->getAuthPassword() to the value of $credentials['password'].
>   This method should return true or false indicating on whether the
>   password is valid.

So, for simplicity the **retrieveByCredentials()** method returns a mocked **User** object (that implements the **Authenticatable** interface).

This is my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Authentication;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider as IlluminateUserProvider;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use function GuzzleHttp\json_encode;
use function GuzzleHttp\json_decode;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class UserProvider implements IlluminateUserProvider
{
    public function retrieveById($identifier)
    {
        // TODO: Implement retrieveById() method.
        \Log::info('retrieveById START');

    }

    public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)
    {
        // TODO: Implement retrieveByToken() method.
        \Log::info('retrieveByToken START');
    }

    public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token)
    {
        // TODO: Implement updateRememberToken() method.
        \Log::info('updateRememberToken START');
    }

    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials) {

        // TODO: Implement retrieveByCredentials() method.

        \Log::info('retrieveByCredentials START');
        \Log::info('INSERTED USER CREDENTIAL: '.$credentials['email'] . ' ' .$credentials['password']);

        $client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client

        $response = $client->get('http://localhost:8080/Extranet/login',
            [
                'auth' => [
                    'nobili.andrea@gmail.com',
                    'pswd'
                ]
            ]);

        $dettagliLogin = json_decode($response->getBody());

        \Log::info('response: '.(json_encode($dettagliLogin)));

        $user = new User('Pippo', 'pippo@google.com', true);

        \Log::info('USER: '.(json_encode($user)));

        return $user;


    }

    public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials)
    {
        // TODO: Implement validateCredentials() method.
        \Log::info('validateCredentials START');
    }

}
```

an this is the code of the returned **User** object (as you can see it contains the information obtained by the **JSON** from my web service):

```
<?php

namespace App\Authentication;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class User implements Authenticatable {

    private $username;
    private $email;
    private $enabled;

    /**
     * User constructor.
     * @param $username
     * @param $email
     * @param $enabled
     */
    public function __construct($username, $email, $enabled)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->enabled = $enabled;
    }


    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifierName() {
        // Return the name of unique identifier for the user (e.g. "id")

    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier() {
        // Return the unique identifier for the user (e.g. their ID, 123)
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword() {
        // Returns the (hashed) password for the user
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberToken() {
        // Return the token used for the "remember me" functionality
    }

    /**
     * @param  string $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setRememberToken($value) {
        // Store a new token user for the "remember me" functionality
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberTokenName() {
        // Return the name of the column / attribute used to store the "remember me" token
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $username
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $email
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEnabled()
    {
        return $this->enabled;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $enabled
     */
    public function setEnabled($enabled)
    {
        $this->enabled = $enabled;
    }

}
```

So my **retrieveByCredentials()** method returns this **User** instance containing the mocked user information but I have the following problem:

after the login form submission, the **retrieveByCredentials()** is executed and the **User** instance is returned but I don't access to the index page and I see this error message: **These credentials do not match our records.**

[image]

From what I have understand this error message should be referred the Laravel standard authentication (on the DB), but I am absolutely not sure about this assertion.

How is it possible? I am creating a **custom user provider** in which my **retrieveByCredentials()** implements my custom logic.

What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I try to fix this issue and obtain the access after my **Custom User Providers** login?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide username and password from your form within request. You can do classic php way or to with ajax. Anyhow you will need following code at your backend function.

To login user using custom information you can use Auth::attempt. For example:

```
if(Auth::attempt([
 'username' => $request->username, 
 'password' => $request->password
])){

   # success -> redirect user to home page.
   return redirect()->route('home');

}else{
   # return error.
   $errors = new MessageBag(['password' => ['Email and/or password invalid.']]);

   return redirect()->back()->with(['errors' => $errors]); // For PHP.
   return response()->json(['errors' => $errors]); // For Ajax.
}
```

Also you can use loginUsingId method. But first you have to find user in your database.

```
$user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

if($user){
 # Check for password match.
 if($request->password == $user->getAuthPassword()){
   Auth::loginUsingId($user->id, true) /*You will have to get user id from database
                                       or to know somehow what user id is. 
                                       Second param (true) is for remembering user.*/
 }
}
else{
  # User does not exist. return error.
}
```

Don't forget to include classes in your class.

```
use App\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
```